# CMD window Close automatically after Jenkins build is over

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I trying to run Selenium grid and node using Jenkins but the CMD windows always closes after executing the steps 
i am running the below code in Jenkins Window Batch Command

```
cd "C:\TapsiumACSS\Grid3.9"
start Hub.bat
```

I need the CMD window to be opened

Comment: You can try with selenium plugin instead of cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a shortcut of the bat file and under properties in the target section you have to add &PAUSE

This will pause the command prompt until an user input is done.

[image]

Just a opinion, Not a good idea to use Jenkins and ask the user to do something as that defeats the whole automation aspect... Instead copy the selenium results into a html or text file which can be viewed later :)

P.S. you will have to refer to this bat file location in Jenkins i.e. the shortcut location

Hope it helps :)